# Regex to match and capture a word

Tags: regex, perl

I wrote a regex in a perl script to find and capture a word that contains the sequence `"fp"`, `"fd"`, `"sp"` or `"sd"` in a sentence. However, the word may contain some non-word characters like θ or ð. The word may be at the beginning or end of the sentence. When I tested this regex on [regex101.com](http://www.regex101.com), it matches even when the input is nothing.The way I interpret this regex is: match one of the patterns "fp", "fd", "sp" or "sd" and capture everything around it until either a whitespace or the beginning of the line on the left side and a whitespace or end of the line on the right side.

This is the regex: `^|\s(.*[fs][ˈ|ˌ]?[pd].*)\s|$`

I also tried using the `?` quantifier to make the `.*` pattern lazy, but it still shows a match when the input is nothing.

Here are some examples of what I need it to capture in parentheses:

```
(fpgθ) tig <br/>
tig (gfpθ) tig<br/>
tig (gθfp)<br/>
```

Edit: I forgot to explain the middle part. The `[ˈˌ]?` part (I made a mistake, I don't need the `|`) just allows for those characters to be between the `[fs]` and `[pd]`. I wouldn't want it to match things like `tigf pg`. I want it to match any word (defined by the space around it - so in a sentence like `tig you rθð`the words it contains are `tig`, `you`, and `rθð`). This "word" could be at the end, at the beginning, or in the middle of the sentence. Is there a way to assert the position at the beginning of the string within a bracket? I think that would solve my problem.

Also, I tried using `\w`, but because I have things like `θ` or `ð` it doesn't match those.

Comment: Looks like you need something like `/\w*[fs][pd]\w*/g`. Your regex contains alternation opertors and two of the alternatives allow empty string mstch at the start and end of the string.

Comment: Your pattern `^|\s(.*[fs][ˈ|ˌ]?[pd].*)\s|$` says to match the beginning of a line, or `\s(.*[fs][ˈ|ˌ]?[pd].*)\s`, or the end of a line. Clearly any string has a beginning and an end, so any data will match. It's hard to know what you mean by the middle part `\s(.*[fs][ˈ|ˌ]?[pd].*)\s`. I think you need to give examples of what should and should not match for us to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is still a little openness in the description, but this works with shown data

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use utf8;
use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)";

my @strs = ( 
    '(fpgθ) tig <br/>',
    'tig (gfpθ) tig<br/>',
    'tig (gθfp)<br/>',
);

for (@strs) 
{
    my @m = /\b( \S*? [fs][pd] \S*? )\b/gx; 

    say "@m" if @m;   # no space allowed by the pattern
}
```

Depending on clarifications you may want to tweak the `\S` and `\b` that are used. I capture into an array, with `/g`, for strings with more than one match. I left parentheses in for an additional test.

The [`use utf8`](http://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html) allows UTF-8 in the source, so it's for my `@strs` array only.

The [`use open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/open.html) pragma, however, is essential as it sets default (PerlIO) input and output layers, in this case standard streams for `UTF-8`.  So you can read from a file and print to a file or console.

Answer (score 1):

> find and capture a word that contains the sequence "fp", "fd", "sp" or
>   "sd" in a sentence. However, the word may contain some non-word
>   characters like θ or ð.

You should match Unicode letters `\p{L}` instead of regular word characters `\w`:

[`\p{L}*[fs][pd]\p{L}*`](https://regex101.com/r/MdjQnf/2)

Click on the pattern to try it online. I have simplified the pattern according to your latest edits.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use utf8;
use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)";

my @regex = qr/\p{L}*[fs][pd]\p{L}*/mp;
my @strs = 'fpgθ tig <br/>
tig gfpθ tig<br/>
tig gθfp<br/>
fptig gfpθ tig<br/>
sddgsdθ(θ@) tig gθfp<br/>';

for (@strs) 
{
    my @m = /@regex/gm;
    print "@m" if @m;   # no space allowed by the pattern
}
```